# I am trying to delete Items from in a TODO-LIST App using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to delete list items from localStorage but nothing happens when I click the delete button. Just to be clear, the delete button was working just fine until I got to the point of trying to delete Items from localStorage. I have a console.log(items) inside `deleteFromLocalStorage()`  to test out if the function is running when I call it inside the `deleteItem()`  which I thought would return some data but still, nothing happens. Please here is the code, help me fix this.

```
//Deleting Items from the List 
const deleteButton = container.querySelectorAll('.trash-icon');


let deleteItem = (event)=> {
   event.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
   deleteFromLocalStorage(item);
}

deleteButton.forEach((button)=> {
    button.addEventListener("click", deleteItem);
});


//SAVING TO LOCAL STORAGE

function savingToLocalStorage(item) {
    let items;
    if(localStorage.getItem("items") === null) {
        items = [];
    } else {
        items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));
    }

    items.push(item);
    localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
}

//Retrieving From Local Storage 
function retrievingFromLocalStorage(item) {
    let items;
    if(localStorage.getItem("items") === null) {
        items = [];
    } else {
        items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));
    }

    items.forEach((item)=> {
        const todoDIV = document.createElement("div");
        todoDIV.classList.add("todo--item");
        todoDIV.innerHTML = `
        
        <div>
         <input type="radio" name="radio" class="radioBtn">
         <li class="list--item">${item}</li>
         </div>
         <div>
         <i class="fas fa-trash trash-icon"></i>
         </div>
        
        `
        listContainer.appendChild(todoDIV);
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", retrievingFromLocalStorage());


//Delete from Local Storage 

function deleteFromLocalStorage(item) {
    let items;

    if(localStorage.getItem("items") === null) {
        items = [];
    } else {
        items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));
    }
    console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: `deleteFromLocalStorage()` never deletes anything.

Comment: You never set the variable `item` when calling `deleteFromLocalStorage()` from `deleteItem()`.

Comment: Unrelated problem: You shouldn't have `()` in `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", retrievingFromLocalStorage());`

Comment: You have `console.log(item)` not `console.log(items)`.

Answer (score 0):

After yo retrieve the items from local storage, you should find the item being deleted in that array. Remove it from the array and save back to local storage.

I made an assumption that the todo item has a `name` property that identifies it. You can replace that with whatever you're using to uniquely identify items.

You'll need to update `deleteItem()` so it passes the `item` object to the function. There isn't enough information in the code you've posted for me to show how to find that.

```js
//Delete from Local Storage 

function deleteFromLocalStorage(item) {
  if (localStorage.getItem("items") === null) {
    return; // no items saved, nothing to delete
  }
  let items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));
  let index = items.findIndex(i => i.name == item.name);
  if (index > -1) {
    items.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.putItem("items", JSON.stringify(items);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code for a complete to-do list. You can look at it and see if you learn off of it.

```js
const addButton = document.getElementById("add") // Add button
const input = document.getElementById("Input") // input text plate
const view = document.getElementById("view") // Shows where the todos will view
const inputValue = input.value
var todo = [] // Empty array to put the to dos in
var counter = 0




function inputToDo() { 
  view.innerHTML += `<span id="${counter}">${input.value} 
  <button id="X" onclick="xButton(this)" class="xButton">X</button> <br> </span> `
}
  // Button makes a button right next to do todo
  
function xButton(elem){
  elem.parentNode.remove()
}
```

```html
<button id="add" onclick="inputToDo()" class="add">Add</button>


<label  for="Input">Input a Todo</label>
<input id="Input">

<div id="view"></div> 


<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where does it save to local storage?

Comment: The part of his code that removes from the DOM looks like it works, the issue is with local storage, and your code has nothing like that.

Comment: I'm intermediate. I just showed him my code for a to-do list that i made.

Comment: You have to read the whole question, not just the title. His specific problem is with deleting the item from local storage.

Comment: You can answer his questions instead of barking at me :)

Comment: The question is unanswerable as it's currently written. He doesn't show how `item` is set, or what the objects look like so you can find the item in a list.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).